# Why aren't all functions inlined?

Tags: c++, inline

If the implementation of an inlined function is placed everywhere that the function is called in the code, and this saves two branch steps, shouldn't a programmer try to inline every function if they do not have to worry about space ?

To be more specific, I would think that executing the function body immediately would always be faster than branching to the function body, executing the function body, and branching back to where the function call was made.

Comment: Two words: Cache, Recursion (and before you flame me, this is a comment, not an answer)

Comment: You're confusing some things here. A function call is *not* branching. Either way, decades of brilliant engineers' brainpower has gone into optimizing both branch predictors and function calls in hardware. These days, you are very likely to make performance worse if you try to outsmart this elaborate system.

Comment: Compilers can do that for you (if you ask for it), it's called auto-inlining.

Comment: There's a non-zero cost associated with inlining, it produces more code.  Which uses the L1 and TLB instruction caches less efficiently.  Finding the balance between the loss of cache efficiency and the gain from omitting function calls is important.  Typically found by a simple heuristic based on the function size and/or data gathered during profile guided optimization instrumenting.

Comment: @us2012
Maybe I have it confused, but I've coded a little in assembly and every time we made a function call, we used a branch instruction and stored the address of the next instruction in the link register ( so the branch instruction at the end of the function knew where to return to ).

Comment: @KacyRaye I think the generally accepted defintion of a branch ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_(computer_science) ) is that the execution flow actually splits into multiple possibilities at that point. A function call can be considered a special case of a *jump*, but not really a *branch*.

Comment: In other words, a branch can have conditions ( like an if statement ), while a jump does not depend on any conditions.
Now that my terminology is corrected, I'm hoping someone can clearly explain why immediate execution of the function body is not preferred for the sake of speed over 2 jumps and execution of the funciton body.

Comment: @KacyRaye: it has been explained, perhaps not clearly enough. The code with all functions inlined is bigger. Therefore it occupies more cache space, and crucially it evicts more other code from cache. A cache miss is much more expensive than a jump, so it is by no means a guaranteed win to increase code size in order to reduce the number of jumps. Optimizing compilers use a better (and more complex) strategy than just, "inline everything possible".

Comment: Also, be aware that the programmer doesn't get to decide whether a function is inlined or not. The compiler does. Marking a function `inline` does not require it to be inlined at every call site. Even duplicating the code at every call site (with a macro, for example) doesn't *necessarily* cause it to appear in the binary at every call site, compilers can and occasionally do de-duplicate code.

Comment: @SteveJessop Thank you! Your explanation combined with Benjamin's answer below answered my question perfectly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> shouldn't a programmer try to inline every function if they do not
>   have to worry about space ?

Yes.  But in most real world applications, you do have to worry about space.  Programs and data which take up less space are (generally speaking) faster.  Read about [cache misses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Cache_miss).  Of course, programs which execute fewer instructions are also (generally speaking) faster, which is why we inline.  These two ideas are in direct conflict, and so a balance must be met.  It is usually best to leave this balancing act up to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

No. One of the benefits of functions is to make code reusable. If a programmer inlines all his functions then the code base increases and maintenance increases. If the compiler chooses to inline the functions later for the sake of speed or efficiency this doesn't impact on the maintenance aspect, and retains the readability of the original code.

Comment: I've never heard of maintenance when it comes to the code.  Not that I don't believe you, but can you slightly elaborate on that a bit more? If the maintenance increases, does the time your program take to execute increase?

Comment: Maintenance: any occasion when code changes are required. This could be for bug fixes, spec changes, or any other reason.

Comment: I don't believe the OP is referring to manual inlining in the source code (except as far as adding the inline specifier to function definitions, but that doesn't affect maintainability).

Comment: The point is that in order to inline every function, every function that's called from a translation unit must be visible in its entirety in that translation unit. So when you make even the most trivial change to the code in that function you have to recompile every translation unit that uses that function. Separating interface from implementation is a good thing: it means you don't have to recompile the world when you make a trivial change. inline is an **optimization** that works against granularity and, hence, maintainability. Unless it has a clear benefit, it just makes coding harder.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above comments the inline functions are loaded at the start of your program which gives u idea that if all inlined then load becomes heavy on compiler which becomes bad on programmer side